# Redirection url using urllib in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, redirect, urllib

I would need to know what is my final URL when following redirections using urllib in Python 3.

Let's say I've some code like :

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
u = opener.open(request)
```

If my urls redirects to another website, how can I know this new website URL ? I've found nothing useful in documentation.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` is the updated version and was all that was necessary for me, plus an exception handler for errors like `404`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use

```
u.geturl()
```

to get the URL you were redirected to (or the original one if no redirect happened).

Comment: Thanks, I got to it as you posted your response :)